# How to avoid sending null fields with JsonFX

Tags: c#, json, serialization, jsonfx

In the codebase I am woking on, the most common object that is serialized in json has 3 fields. The value of one of these fields is often, but not always, null.

I was asked to avoid sending the field in the json build if its value is null. And I don't see how to do it. The JsonFX Annotations I know only allow to ignore a field whatever its value (JsonIgnore), or to transform the value of a field (using JsonName and properties )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip nulls unconditionally for all properties and fields of all types, you can subclass your [`IResolverStrategy`](https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx/blob/master/src/JsonFx/Serialization/Resolvers/IResolverStrategy.cs) (which is likely [`JsonResolverStrategy`](https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx/blob/master/src/JsonFx/Json/Resolvers/JsonResolverStrategy.cs) or [`PocoResolverStrategy`](https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx/blob/master/src/JsonFx/Serialization/Resolvers/PocoResolverStrategy.cs)), override [`GetValueIgnoredCallback(MemberInfo member)`](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/JsonFx/JsonFx/JsonResolverStrategy/M/GetValueIgnoredCallback), and return a delegate that skips null values:

```
public class SkipNullJsonResolverStrategy : JsonResolverStrategy // Or PocoResolverStrategy
{
    public override ValueIgnoredDelegate GetValueIgnoredCallback(MemberInfo member)
    {
        Type type;
        if (member is PropertyInfo)
            type = ((PropertyInfo)member).PropertyType;
        else if (member is FieldInfo)
            type = ((FieldInfo)member).FieldType;
        else
            type = null;

        var baseValueIgnored = base.GetValueIgnoredCallback(member);
        if (type != null && (!type.IsValueType || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null))
        {
            return (ValueIgnoredDelegate)((instance, memberValue) => (memberValue == null || (baseValueIgnored != null && baseValueIgnored(instance, memberValue))));
        }
        else
        {
            return baseValueIgnored;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
        var settings = new DataWriterSettings(new SkipNullJsonResolverStrategy());
        var writer = new JsonWriter(settings);

        var json = writer.Write(rootObject);
```

If you only want to skip nulls on selected properties, you need to use `JsonResolverStrategy` (or a subclass), and then either

- Set [`[DefaultValue(null)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the property, OR
- Set [`[JsonSpecifiedProperty(string methodName)]`](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/JsonFx/JsonFx/JsonSpecifiedPropertyAttribute) on the property to specify the name of *another* property that returns `false` when the the property is to be skipped.

For instance:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    [JsonSpecifiedProperty("NameSpecified")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    bool NameSpecified { get { return Name != null; } }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public int? NullInteger { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public DateTime? NullableDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using JsonFx v1 or v2? If v2, then @dbc gave multiple good ways. If using v1, then use `[DefaultValueAttribute(null)]`.